# Business Intelligence Development Studio encounter error on Rendering

Tags: .net, reporting-services, report

I try to develop a data processing extension for SSRS 2008 in order to access database through an entity framework. But when I copy and register the extension in BI Development Studio, it gives me an error message while loading the extension". I built it with targeting framework 4.0 by using Visual Studio 2010 because my data model class library was built with that version of target framework.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I use the SSRS ReportViewer from VS 2008 in a VS2010 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453426/how-can-i-use-the-ssrs-reportviewer-from-vs-2008-in-a-vs2010-project)

Not sure if that is entirely relevant, but might point you in the right direction